# Attribute Dict -- TypeError raised when getting documentation

Tags: python-2.7, keyerror

I wrote an "AttributeDict"-like object from the Alchin 'pro python' book, (below is taken almost directly from the book. My goal is to create a config object where the config fields are accessible as class attributes).

```
class ADict(dict):
    def __setattr__(self,key,value):
        self[key] = value
    def __getattr__(self,key):
        return self[key]
```

When I try to access the documentation I get a TypeError, related to a missing __name__ attribute (example below).

```
>>> z = ADict()
>>> help(z)
line 1531, in doc
pager(render_doc(thing, title, forceload))
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pydoc.py",   line 1505, in render_doc
object, name = resolve(thing, forceload)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pydoc.py", line 1500, in resolve
name = getattr(thing, '__name__', None)
File "attributeConfig.py", line 26, in __getattr__
return self[key]
KeyError: '__name__'
```

What's going on here? It's not obvious to me where this __name__ is going to (and how it's being used in the pydoc code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure an `AttributeError` is raised when the attribute couldn't be found:

```
class ADict(dict):

    def __setattr__(self,key,value):
        self[key] = value

    def __getattr__(self,key):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError
```

This will lookup the attribute in the dictionary first. If it's there, return it. Otherwise, use raise an `AttributeError` to indicate that the attribute isn't there.

Comment: whan you would call `z = ADict()` and than: `z.__name__` you will get `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'`

Comment: @ambi fixed now, the method should raise an `AttributeError` instead.

Comment: @SimeonVisser Okay, thanks. this work. What's the deal with the missing \_\_name\_\_ attribute in the first place? (I'm new to magic methods in python, so I apologize if this is super obvious).

Comment: @user1151034: I think when you call `help()` it gathers as much as it can about the object, including a `__name__` attribute. If it doesn't have it, that's fine, but in this case the missing attribute wasn't handled by your class properly. If the name was there, I think it would've been displayed in the help details.

Comment: @user1151034: in general you can call `help()` on anything and you can also manually delete `__name__` attributes. So `help()` can look for things that aren't there anyway. There's no guarantee that attributes will be there (as this shows) but `help()` tries anyway to see if it can retrieve information there.